# retrieve the value of a cell if it belongs to a specific column

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a table where when you click on a cell, i print the value of that cell on *verbatimTextOutput()*.

I would like to know how to retrieve only the values of a cell belonging to **column** **a** and if i click elsewhere i keep the last value of the clicked cell belonging to **column** **a**

```
    library(shiny)

    ui <- fluidPage(
      DT::dataTableOutput("table"),
      verbatimTextOutput("output", placeholder = TRUE)
    )

    server <- function(input, output) {

      output$output <- renderText({
        #val()
        input$table_cell_clicked$value

      })

      val <- reactive(
        if(input$table_cell_clicked$col==1){
          input$table_cell_clicked$value
        } else{ }
      )

      # the datatable
        dt <- data.frame("a" = paste("a", 1:10), "b" = paste("b", 1:10))
        output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
          DT::datatable(dt, select="none")})
    }

    # Run the application
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using `reactiveVal()` to store value of valid last clicked cell. Also see comments for more info.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("table"),
  verbatimTextOutput("output", placeholder = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  dt <- data.frame("a" = paste("a", 1:10), "b" = paste("b", 1:10))

  # the datatable
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(dt, select="none")
  })

  val <- reactiveVal() # val stores value of valid last clicked cell

  observe({
    req(input$table_cell_clicked$col == 1) # if() will work as well but req() is cleaner
    val(input$table_cell_clicked$value) # update val() only if cell is in column 1
  })

  output$output <- renderPrint({
    val()
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```